# How do I force a refresh of the WiFi network list?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster

Is it possible to force a refresh of the list of networks that appear on the Raspberry Pi desktop connection manager? E.g. To connect to hotspot on my phone. It takes what seems like a long time before the hotspot will finally appear.

Comment: Why are you doing this? You can setup with multiple networks, and set connection priorities.

Answer (score 0):

I did a full update (`sudo apt full-upgrade`) and now it seems the network list in the WiFi menu is updated in real-time. So it looks like the upgrade solved my problem.